# Finding Unknown Vector Using Its Projection

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Find two vectors whose projection on the vector $(-3, 1)$ is $(\frac{-3}{2}, \frac12)$

Conceptually I understand that the vectors are those that make an angle $\theta $ or $-\theta$ with the vector given. However I don't understand how to find that angle using the given information, I always seem to run into the issue of now knowing the magnitude of the unknown vector. Answer should relate to the dot product

Comment: If  $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ are two vectors, then the inner product is defined as $$\vec A \cdot \vec B=|\vec A| \,|\vec B| \, \cos(\theta)$$where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec A$ and $\vec B$.  Moreover, the inner product is given by $\sum_{i=1}^2 A_iB_i$.

Answer (score 1):

There are not just two vectors that satisfy this condition - there are infinitely many. Construct a line through the point $(-\frac 3 2, \frac 1 2)$ that is perpendicular to the line $x+3y=0$. A vector from the origin to any point on this line will have the required projection.

Comment: Thank you! this was very helpful!